# How to detect if music is playing on iOS in AIR app

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I've seen a native call to test if music is playing via the Music app on iOS, but I'm having trouble discovering if there's a native AS3 call or an ANE that can do the same? I have a game with it's own music, but I'd like to automatically disable that music if the player already has music playing.

Comment: You ever find a solution to this? I have the exact same issue.

Comment: Not as yet. :\ It also hasn't been a high enough priority to build something myself.

Answer (score 0):

Will be necessary to create a custom ANE (I don't know if already exist one with this feature).
I believe will be quite simple.
Try to follow these steps

- Include the AVFoundation framework
- Import: #import
- Create a method to check. Follow just an example

FREObject isMusicPlaying(FREContext ctx, void* funcData, uint32_t argc, FREObject argv[]) 
{

BOOL retunValue;

AVAudioPlayer *audioplayer;
   returnValue = (audioplayer.playing) ? YES : NO;

FREObject retStr = NULL;
   FRENewObjectFromBool(returnValue, retStr);

return retStr;

}